# Can a Laurent polynomial be written as one exponentiation?

Tags: polynomials

Polynomial with positive exponents can be written as one exponentiation with a constant term. For example, the quadratic function $f(x) = x^2-10x+35$ can be written as $f(x) = \left(x-5\right)^2+10$.

Laurent polynomials include functions such as:

$$f(x)=x+x^{-1}$$

Can a Laurent polynomial with negative exponents be rewritten as one exponentiation with a constant term? If so, how could the above function be rewritten in this form?

Comment: How would you write $f(x)=x^3+x$ as an "exponentiation" plus a constant?

Comment: @Dave Hmm, my apologies for not looking into it more. I think that these polynomials can be written as one tetration (repeated exponentiation) by a constant. Is this correct or verifiable?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then no. The tetration would still be an exponentiation. Again, how would you factor my $f(x)$ example above in this fashion?

Comment: I see, thank you. The only way I can think of with your example is $f(x)=x^{log_x(x^3+x)}$, which is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm essentially looking to see if there is a property of exponents over addition that can be written with one usage of $x$.

Comment: I don't think this is something you can do with polynomials let alone Laurent polynomials. There are special cases though, for instance if the polynomial is quadratic or something like $$f(x)=x^2+x^{-2}=(x+x^{-1})^2-2$$

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Can any polynomial be expressed as transformations on its parent function by constants? For example, can $f(x) = x^3+x$ be expressed in this way? Quadratics can be expressed in the form $f(x) = a(x-h)^2+k$, does this generalize to other polynomials?

I think I may make post a new question on this haha.